# Laravel Query builder insert 1 value higher than last record

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a problem with laravel query builder. I have a query, which contains one value INT. It should be always 1 higher than last record in database. And I don't know how to do it in Laravel Query builder. In raw SQL I would do

```
INSERT INTO table_name (name, order)
VALUES ('ahoy', order + 1);
```

And it should work. But I have really no idea how to do it in laravel query builder

Comment: Is that valid SQL syntax? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95a3e6/1

Comment: Maybe not. I have used something like this few years ago, but I don't understand the correct syntax

Answer (score 1):

You could use `increments()` in a migration file instead of `integer`. But you also will need to [drop primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#dropping-indexes):

```
Schema::create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('order');
});

Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropPrimary('table_name_order_primary');
});
```

Comment: I need the primary key to be on the other cell. It must be on cell ID. But I need increment also for the ORDER column. I tried to set it directly in PHPmyadmin, but I have received an error.

Comment: @MegoSoft is the ID auto-incrementing?